# Why does ArcGIS Online project my files right where they should be but, ArcGIS for desktop does not

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, coordinate-system, arcgis-online

When loading shapefiles into Arc Map 10.2.2 I get the message saying "unknown spatial reference", then my files are not projected where they should be and are usually too small to see regardless how much I zoom in. When I load the same files into ArcGIS Online they load fine and are projected exactly as they should.

If the spatial reference is unknown to ArcMap then how can ArcGIS Online know how to reference them?

Comment: Also when I change the spatial reference for these shapfiles to match the spatial reference of other shapfiles that load correctly, they still do not load as they should.

Comment: I'd assume it's because ArcMap doesn't hazard to guess and ArcGIS online assumes WGS 1984 for everything. What spatial reference are you changing them to? Chances are the coordinates aren't in the spatial ref you're manually changing it to.

Comment: I am changing them to: NAD_1983_StatePlane_Massachusetts_Mainland_FIPS_2001_Feet

Comment: Chances are they're WGS 1984 if AGOL is magically getting it right.

Comment: what process are you using to change them. I suspect this is the issue as to change them correctly you generally need a prj file and your unknown spatial reference is telling me is does not have one. Tells us the steps you are making to change it.

Comment: I was going to the shapefile properties through the catalog in arcmap, then adding a reference through the xy coordinate system tab. I was looking for projections in the North American datums or state plane datums, didn't try generalizing it to a world geo-coordinate system. Jason was right though, it was WGS 1984

Comment: You need to use the Project tool. Setting a coordinate system in the shapefile's properties tab doesn't work. That might define a projection, but doesn't actually set it. The only time you can set a projection in a properties type way is when you create the shapefile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the conversation on the comments, ArcGIS online is making a guess at the coordinate system, while ArcMap is not. When it encounters an unknown coordinate system, ArcGIS Online appears to automatically assume WGS 1984. ArcGIS for Desktop treats undefined coordinate systems differently and does not make assumptions about the data's actual coordinate system.

The statement about the default coordinate system is discussed in step 4 of ["*Publish a shapefile or CSV file*" section here](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/share-maps/publish-features.htm#GUID-DD47C642-38B4-4645-801D-2866FE90BF73). The data extent is checked to ensure that the coordinate values make sense for latitude-longitude data.